# Can't run BAT file to generate a custom date?

Tags: batch-file, dos, windows-shell

I run the following code in DOS shell to generate a SCR file that I will then use to connect to a FTP server and download files.

```
echo open myftp.mywebsite.com >> myscript.SCR
echo myusername >> myscript.SCR
echo mypassword >> myscript.SCR
echo lcd "C:\myfolder" >> myscript.SCR
echo cd outgoing >> myscript.SCR
```

The above runs fine, but the BAT file gets hung up with the below code

```
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %i in ('date /t') do echo get mydownloadfile_%k%i%j.TXT >> myscript.SCR
```

Anyone know of a workaround for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly as it is but you can use date/time slicing, e.g.:

```
echo %date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2% >> mydate.scr
```

This specific string is locale dependent and will only work with a US locale. For other locales you'll need to adjust the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Per **ccpizza**'s answer above, I also often do use the built in string manipulation features and that works fine for US Date format.

However if you need to ensure that *non-US dates* (date parts in a different order) will work, then this is an option for you.

```
for %%A IN (%Date%) do ( for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/-" %%B in ("%%~A") do ( set MyDate=%%D%%B%%C ) )
echo get mydownloadfile_%MyDate%.txt >> myscript.SCR
```

Rearrange the date parts in the file name to be right for your file name format.

- %%D = year
- %%B = month
- %%C = day